# Explain づき in the given sentence

Tags: grammar

First of all, hi everyone.

In the beginning of an anime episode I often see a message to turn on the lights in the room and not to sit too close to the screen. Leaving some stuff out it looks like this:

テレビアニメを見る時は、近**づき**すぎない**ようにして見て**くださいね。

Note the bolded parts. I have 2 questions.

I looked up づき in the dictionary, it's like "to be attached, to be included".
Does づき make it a verb? An adverb? Or what is it?
Is it a state "being attached to a TV"? Or is it an action "do not attach yourself to a TV"?

2nd question about ようにして見る.
As I understand ようにする is "to try".
So as て-form + みる.
Doesn't it make it kind of redundant to use both at the same time? Is it common?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first situation, づき is not its own word. It's part of the verb 近{ちか}づく, which means "to get near," which has been conjugated to fit the ～すぎる construction, so it becomes 近づきすぎる, or "get too close."

You have a slight misunderstanding on the second one. While ～てみる *does* have the meaning of try in many situations, this is a case where it doesn't and in fact it is using the literal meaning of 見る. Your clue to this can be the fact that the 見る is written with kanji whereas in the てみる "try" construction it is usually written without kanji.

So to break it down a little more, 近づきすぎないようにして means something like "be careful that you're not too close," and connected to 見る it's advising you not to sit too closely to the TV *when watching*.

Comment: This clears about everything that puzzled me. Many thanks! Very good explanation.

Comment: is the よう in the ようにして here meaning "state"? As in, "Please watch this, 'in the state' of not being too close." ?

Comment: @yadokari そうそう、この「よう」は漢字で書くと、「様」。「～～しないように気を付けてください」「～～しないよう、ご注意ください」というときの。

Comment: @Chocolate、説明してくれてありがとうございます〜